# Add values from multiple checkboxes to same row in database with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I've been researching this for 2 days but have yet to find an adequate solution to my issue. Essentially I am trying to "link" database rows by ID based on multiple check boxes using jQuery, but here is where it gets a little tricky:

#### Background:

- I have a database table (`positions`) displayed as an HTML table (`#ct`) with check boxes next to each row.
- Up to four (4) rows can be checked at a time and "linked" to one another (but don't worry about the limit of number of boxes that can be checked)
- Linking the rows from `positions` SHOULD create one new row in `covered_positions` with columns `id`(PK), `linked_id1`, `linked_id2`, `linked_id3`, `linked_id4`

#### What is already done:

- Each checkbox *already* has its value assigned to the respective row `id` in `positions`
- A dropdown select box *already* triggers the Javascript function `ctActions()`

#### What I *think* is needed:

- Create an array in **`ctActions()`** of the checkbox values using something like:

  ```
  var linked_ids = [];

  $("#ct input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
      linked_ids.push(this.value);
  });
  ```
- Encode and send the data to PHP:

  ```
  var linked_ids_json = JSON.stringify(linked_ids);

  $.post('link-positions.php', { linked_ids_json: linked_ids_json } );
  ```

---

- In my **`link-positions.php`**:

  ```
  // Get & explode array
  $array = json_decode($_POST['linked_ids_json']);

  // Test whether each value is set -- Not sure if needed
  $linked_id1 = (isset($array[0]) ? $array[0] : "");
  $linked_id2 = (isset($array[1]) ? $array[1] : "");
  $linked_id3 = (isset($array[2]) ? $array[2] : "");
  $linked_id4 = (isset($array[3]) ? $array[3] : "");

  include('../mysqli-connect.php');
  $conn = dbConnect();

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `covered_positions` (
      linked_id1,
      linked_id2,
      linked_id3,
      linked_id4)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param('iiii',
              $linked_id1,
              $linked_id2,
              $linked_id3,
              $linked_id4);

  $stmt->execute();

  $conn->close();
  ```

But after all this, nothing happens. I'm sure there are some blatant errors in my code so I thought I would post it for some more experienced eyes.

#### UPDATES

- Fixed `$stmt->execute` to `$stmt->execute()` but still does not solve issue.

Comment: +1 for the very detailed question, though "nothing happens" is not really a valid problem. A good start is by opening Chrome dev tools' Network tab or Firebug's Net tab before sending the ajax and it will display the response from your php.

Comment: Shouldn't `$stmt->execute;` be `$stmt->execute();` in `link-positions.php`?

Comment: on top of the `->execute` stuff, you should also add in proper error handling on the DB code. you're simply assuming that each of those calls (connect, prepare, bind, execute) has succeeded. DB operations have exactly **ONE** way to succeed, and a near infinite number of ways to fail. ALWAYS check return values or try/catch db operations.

Comment: have you var_dump'ed the input data on link-positions.php?

Comment: Just used console to discover a 404 for link-positions.php so I simply moved the file to the correct directory and the script works!

Comment: If it's solved, please accept the answer (if that solved your issue), or add your own answer explaining how you solved it, to help future users with a similar problem. Please do not add "solved" to the title or question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The code works fine, just the link-positions.php was in the wrong directory. Hope the code helps others with similar tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the FireBug if the `AJAX` request gets completed succesfully, or any error comes.

Next, check what data you are getting on the server by `print_r($_POST);`

Considering your HTML is like

```
<form id="form1">
    <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="a" name="cbTest[]" />
    <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="b" name="cbTest[]" />
    <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="c" name="cbTest[]" />
    <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="d" name="cbTest[]" />
</form>
```

I would suggest you to get the checked values by using

```
// if the form only contains checkboxes
var linked_ids_json = $('#form1').serialize();

// Or
var linked_ids_json = $('.cb').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'link-positions.php',
    data: linked_ids_json,
    success: function () {
        // callback
    }
});
```

Use in PHP like,

```
$array = $_POST['linked_ids_json'];
```

You'll be able to access the values like `$linked_id[0];`

Comment: Thank you for your input. I unfortunately cannot use the form method because the table is already in a form. I managed to solve the problem however, it was a simply 404 for my link-positions.php.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the OP. This was originally edited into the question body:

> I found link-positions.php file to be in the wrong directory! The code below works just fine.